# how to RST packet drop using python?

Tags: python, packet

I want to implement a simple source code that DROPs all RST packets that come into the computer using Python. What should I do?

Linux servers can be easily set up using the iptables command, but I want to make it Python for use on Mac, Linux, and Windows systems.

Comment: Consider adding more detail, such at the bash command that utilizes `iptables` to accomplish your objective.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping RST packets is a function of the networking firewall built into your operating system.

There is only one way to do it on Linux: with iptables. You could use Python to instruct iptables.

Windows has its own way to add firewall rules. MacOS also has its own way, and each of them is different from the other.

There is no single common way to do this. Therefore, there is no single common way to do this with Python.

Comment: Thank you
Then can I use Python to control the firewall for windows, too?